# How validate massive files name sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I need to validate if the names of files have been upload on my table "TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel".

Starting I have already a table with name of files that I upload from SSIS

the table looks like it :

**tbl_filenames**

RC196012070801
RC196017080401

I need to validate each one of them "RC196012070801,RC196017080401" if they are already on my table "TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel".
I have the idea to do it with a store procedure but I dont know exactly how
because for example if the first was already entered on the table "TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel" then should not insert it and show simply a messague and continue with the second and on.

I am doing it for now :

```
create procedure sp_validateFile_Entel
@nomfile varchar(14)
as

declare @ncant int

select @ncant = count(*) from TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel where s_Empresa_Code = 'cperu' and s_Nombre_Vol = @nomfile
```

This just will accept one file and I dont need it .I need read one to one and validate if some of them was charged  Please help me with it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you using SQL 2005, 2008 and 2012 at the same time with one procedure? Don't spam tags... also I don't understand how you are using "charged" here. Do you mean changed (like the file was modified)?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. But in the meantime you should consider a different prefix than sp_ (or even better no prefix at all). The sp_ prefix can cause you some issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: To help with your question we need some more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @JacobH . I taged it all them for a solution if someone know it thats why. I meant if they are find out on my table !

Comment: I am being clear with the question simply need to validate the names of files like shows on my table "tbl_filenames" . If one of these names of file exist on my table TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1
To only insert one file at a time if it doesn't already exist

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel') IS NULL
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel AS RETURN 0;');
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel
@nomfile VARCHAR(14)
AS
BEGIN
    --Only insert new record if @nomfile does NOT exist already
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel WHERE s_Empresa_Code = 'cperu' AND s_Nombre_Vol = @nomfile )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel(
            s_Empresa_Code, s_Nombre_Vol
        )
        VALUES(
            'cperu', @nomfile
        );
    END;
END
```

Option 2
To insert using data from existing table [tbl_filenames]

```
--Create the tables
IF OBJECT_ID('TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel;
IF OBJECT_ID('tbl_filenames','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tbl_filenames;

CREATE TABLE TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel ( s_Empresa_Code VARCHAR(20), s_Nombre_Vol VARCHAR(14) )

CREATE TABLE tbl_filenames ( FileNames VARCHAR(14))

--Insert some temp values
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_filenames ( FileNames )
    VALUES ('RC196012070801'), ('RC196012070801' )

--Create the Procedure
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel') IS NULL
  EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel AS RETURN 0;');
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel
    --Input Parameters
AS
BEGIN

    --Only exist if data doesn't exist already
    INSERT INTO TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel(
        s_Empresa_Code, s_Nombre_Vol
     )
    SELECT 'cperu', T.FileNames 
    FROM 
        dbo.tbl_filenames T
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT P.s_Nombre_Vol 
                FROM TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel P 
                WHERE P.s_Empresa_Code = 'cperu' 
                AND P.s_Nombre_Vol = T.FileNames 
            )
END ;
GO

--Exexute the Procedure
EXEC dbo.usp_validateFile_Entel

--Check the Results in the table
SELECT * FROM TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel

--Drop the tables
IF OBJECT_ID('TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TBL_PAGO_DIARIO_Nextel;
IF OBJECT_ID('tbl_filenames','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tbl_filenames;
```